# Can JAXB initialize values in base classes?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-parsing

I am working on a Scala project, and we want to use XML to initialize our objects with JAXB (not Spring). I have a hierarchy where more data members get added in the subclasses. A simple example would look something like this:

```
class Animal
{
   string name
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
   int numLives
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
   bool hasSpots
}
```

I would like to be able to initialize a list of animals from an XML block that looks something like this:

```
<Animals>
   <Cat>
      <name>Garfield</name>
      <numLives>9</numLives>
   </Cat>
   <Dog>
      <name>Odie</name>
      <hasSpots>false</hasSpots>
   </Dog>
</Animals>
```

How would we setup the annotations in the classes to be able to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

For this example you will want to make use of the `@XmlElementRef` and `@XmlRootElement` annotations.  This corresponds to the XML schema concept of substitution groups.  This will allow you to have a list of objects from an inheritance hierarchy differentiated by element.

**Animals**

This will serve as the root object for the domain model.  It has a `List` property annotated with `@XmlElementRef`.  This means it will match values based on the value of their `@XmlRootElement` annotations.

```
package forum8356849;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Animals")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Cat.class, Dog.class})
public class Animals {

    @XmlElementRef
    private List<Animal> animals;
}
```

**Animal**

```
package forum8356849;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Animal
{
   String name;
}
```

**Cat**

We will annotate the `Cat` class with an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.  This is used in tandem with the `@XmlElementRef` annotation on `Animals`.

```
package forum8356849;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Cat")
class Cat extends Animal
{
   int numLives;
}
```

**Dog**

We will also add an `@XmlRootElement` annotation to the `Dog` class.

```
package forum8356849;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Dog")
class Dog extends Animal
{
   boolean hasSpots;
}
```

**Demo**

You can use the following class to see that everything works as expected. `input.xml` corresponds to the XML provided in your question.

```
package forum8356849;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animals.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum8356849/input.xml");
        Animals animals = (Animals) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(animals, System.out);
    }

}
```

**For More Inforation**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: Ahh, I ran into a little snag...  My application needs to support plugins, the `@XmlSeeAlso({Cat.class, Dog.class})` implies that I need to know about my decendents at compile-time.  Any way around that?

Comment: @fbl - You don't need to use XmlSeeAlso but the JAXBContext does need to be aware of the subclasses.  You may find the following approach a better fit:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I prefer creating an XSD schema and generating code from it, so you are on safe side.
But to answer your question, yes, you can. The annotations are XMLElement, XMLAttribute, XMLRootElement.